# Azure Data Factory Denied Delete File on VM with Delete Task

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

I have delete task on Azure Data Factory which I want delete files on VM with FileSystem as Linkedservice.

but i try debug this activity have error and denied permission like this:
[image: the file is forbidden to access]

FYI, i can delete this file from VM with delete manual with press key del on keyboard. big many thanks to answer my question.

Comment: Have you enabled logging ? Can you share if any more error details? The username and password provided at FileSystem linked service has **enough privilege** to delete the source file?

Comment: Can you try using lookup activity to see if you have access to those files

Comment: Ensure the VM is up and running and is accessible by ADF services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have followed [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites) and the **username** and **password** provided at FileSystem linked service has **enough privilege** (write permission) to delete the source file.  (latest version of self-hosted integration runtime, If the access is restricted to IPs that are approved in the firewall rules, you can add [Azure Integration Runtime IPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses) to the allow list)

You can verify access by using a lookup activity with same source file.

In FileSystem linked service you would have to specify the path to a Folder, i.e. "**the root path of the folder or the Azure File Storage endpoint**"
`e.g. C:\[Folder]`

[image]

Next in the Dataset you can further specify the **relative directory** or the **File name**.

[image]

[image]